# New error of type mistmatch on a code that worked great yesterday

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code that sorted data based on the percent error value. The code has been working consistently but this morning I am now getting an error that I was not getting before and I am unsure how to fix it.

I have tried opening the template and restarting my project but I get the same error.

The problem with the code is in this line:

```
If sht1.Range("F" & ii).Value < 0.002 And sht1.Range("F" & ii).Value > -0.002 Then
```

I am getting: `type 13, mismatch error`

Any help would be appreciated, as this code was working yesterday and now I'm stumped on what could have changed.

Comment: What's `ii`? And what's `sht1`? And what data is in the excel workbook at those ranges?

Comment: Looks like the sort of code taht belongs in a loop (`For ii = ...`). You might improve your chances of getting some answer here if you can show more code, and specifically if you can inform what actual data is in the cell when this error raises. I suspect this column contains formula, and that one or more cell returns an Error value, which will raise a mismatch in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `Type mismatch` error when a cell contains an error. You can check this with the `IsError`-function:

```
Dim val As Variant
val = sht1.Range("F" & ii).Value
If Not IsError(val) Then
    If val < 0.002 And val > -0.002 Then
        ' ... Do your work ...
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Yes, this worked great for me. I did find a cell that had a problem, thank you for this snippet of code!